Flow Case Formula to populate Project ID for specific Accounts
I have a flow formula to Increment the number in a text field to populate the ProjectID value. For most Accounts the formula simply takes the first 3 alpha characters of the Account and then assigns the Project ID number incrementally. For some Accounts like Jens Pet Pharma I need to assign a specific alpha character value such as 'JPP'.
My formula is receiving error:The formula expression is invalid: Syntax error. Missing ')'
Anyone know where my syntax might be incorrect?
CASE({!$Record.Account_Name__c},
"Jens Pet Pharma", "JPP & LPAD(TEXT(VALUE(RIGHT({!varlatestProjectId}, 4)) + 1),4,"0"),
"UPPER(LEFT({!$Record.Account.Name}, 3)) & LPAD(TEXT(VALUE(RIGHT({!varlatestProjectId}, 4)) + 1),4,"0")"
)


You have several issues with your formula
CASE({!$Record.Account_Name__c},  // this is OK

the next line says if the Account.Name__c is Jens Pet Pharma, the value of the CASE function should be the concatenation of JPP and some padding
But -- you have a missing quote around "JPP- it should be"JPP"`
  "Jens Pet Pharma", "JPP & LPAD(TEXT(VALUE(RIGHT({!varlatestProjectId}, 4)) + 1),4,"0"),

Then, the Case otherwise clause
"UPPER(LEFT({!$Record.Account.Name}, 3)) & LPAD(TEXT(VALUE(RIGHT({!varlatestProjectId}, 4)) + 1),4,"0")"

has double quotes around a formula expression, turning all of that into a literal string
You want
UPPER(LEFT({!$Record.Account.Name}, 3)) & LPAD(TEXT(VALUE(RIGHT({!varlatestProjectId}, 4)) + 1),4,"0")

and then you need a final ) to complete the CASE function
Putting it all together we have:
CASE({!$Record.Account_Name__c},
 "Jens Pet Pharma", "JPP" & LPAD(TEXT(VALUE(RIGHT({!varlatestProjectId}, 4)) + 1),4,"0"),
 UPPER(LEFT({!$Record.Account.Name}, 3)) & LPAD(TEXT(VALUE(RIGHT({!varlatestProjectId}, 4)) + 1),4,"0")
)

